5.72.0 broke a few things , certainly under Joomla including contribution review and backend searches on the front end
I have detailed various issues with Civi , for example the contribution page not moving onto review and back-end searches published on the front-end not returning any values.
I regressed my test system to CiviCRM to 5.70.0 and then applied updates testing as I went along. All was well until I applied 5.72.0 and it's this release that appears to have caused the issues. 5.72.0 seems to be a large release with various bug fixes and improvements in so my very simple question is this : where the heck do I start trying to work out what bit(s) of 5.72.0 has caused the issues I (and others it seems) are seeing?
Can I apply bits of 5.72.0 and test to see if I can isolate the component that breaks it because installing it its totality will make it hard to troubleshoot.

It can be tedious but git bisect is the way to do it if you have no idea where to start looking.

Wow, that looks interesting and appeals to the nerd in me! Thanks @Demerit
